# Foundation 6 vertical Split Layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation-6

I’m fairly new to this, so sorry if its a bit of a stupid question

I’m trying to achieve a vertical split layout with foundation 6, the site should take up the full width and height of the browser window.

Ideally the right hand side will contain more information than whats there so it needs a separate scroll bar to its-self that doesn’t affect the page height.

I have tried containing it to a div and adding the following styles 
`height: 100% ;
overflow: scroll;`

But either nothing happens or the layout will break completely, so I’m starting to think it might have something to do with my column and row layouts.

Everything so far is in a single row, and was working nicely, also scaled nicely down to mobile view, but I have a bad feeling what I’m doing is wrong.

[Screen Shot of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVWBU.jpg)
[image: Preview Screenshot]

Here is my code so far: (apologies for the novice syntax)

```
<body>
<div class="row full-width large-collapse">
<div class="large-6 medium-12 small-12 columns imgleft"></div>


        <div class="large-6 medium-12 small-12 columns">
            <div class="expanded button-group">
              <a class="button">BUTTON 1</a>
              <a class="button">BUTTON 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="content”>

        <div class="large-6 medium-12 small-12 columns">
            <div class="callout secondary">
              <h5>Panel Heading</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              <a href="#">More</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="large-6 medium-12 small-12 columns">
            <div class="callout secondary">
              <h5>Panel Heading</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              <a href="#">More</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!—x10 More of these callouts—>

    </div>
</div>
</body>


.row.full-width {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
}

.imgleft {
    background-image: url('/img/imgedit.jpg');
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I hope this makes sense…

I have also had a look at nesting, offsetting, changing the position of the image and some jquery solutions, and I haven’t been able to find a solution

Thanks